# Sublimits of a sequence with a factorial

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having trouble finding the sublimits of the sequence:

$b_n= n!^{−1/n}$

I tried to use the even and odd terms but I don't think it's the right way to do it... How can I find the sublimits of this sequence?

Comment: Stirling's formula?  $n!\sim \sqrt {2\pi n} \left( \frac ne \right)^n$ seems helpful.

Comment: Isn't there another way?

Comment: There are some other arguments here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653650/infinite-series-of-nth-root-of-n-factorial

Answer (score 2):

Remember that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_n}n=L$$

And using the Arithmetic-Geometric-Harmonic Progressions inequality (for positive sequences):

$$L=\frac1{\frac1L}\xleftarrow[\infty\leftarrow n]{}\frac n{\frac1{a_1}+\ldots+\frac1{a_n}}\le\sqrt[n]{a_1\cdot\ldots\cdot a_n}\le\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_n}n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}L$$

Apply the above to the sequence $\;\{1,2,...,n,...\}\;$ and get your sequence only has one (partial or whatever) limit: zero.