# is $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n!}{(n-1)^n}$ convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

calculus.
Is $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n!}{(n-1)^n}$ convergent?

i tried ratio test and can't continue. I also tried the root test.

Comment: I assume you mean you tried the ratio and  **root** test?

Comment: yes i meant that thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should show how to tried the ratio test. As I've shown below, it should work out just fine. Root test I think would actually work also assuming you know the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n!}$$

Comment: i dont know that limit. what is it?

Comment: Well, here's a link to that limit: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514388/the-nth-root-of-n?rq=1 however, my memory was mistaken on it and I don't think the root test works well for this example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ratio test: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{(n+1)!}{n^{n+1}}\cdot\dfrac{(n-1)^n}{n!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n+1}{n}\cdot\left(\dfrac{n-1}{n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e^{-1}<1$$

Comment: did you just assume that the 1+1/n would be 0 at infinity so you didn't put it in the last limit?

Comment: No! You can not do that because the exponent is not a constant. This is a well-known type of limit. Here is a link for you to check out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358830/about-lim-left1-frac-xn-rightn and especially: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370125/why-isnt-lim-limits-x-to-infty-left1-frac1x-rightx-equal-to-1?rq=1