# Could someone please tell me why algebra of limit incorrectly used here

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For a sequence ($a_n$) $=$ $(n!)^{1/n}$, how can I show this tend to infinity?

My attempt was that write $(n!)^{1/n}$ = $(n\times...2\times1)^{1/n}$ = $n^{1/n} \times...\times 1^{1/n}$ and since each term has limit 1 then the limit of the sequence is 1 by AOL? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Take logarithm and the see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cesàro_summation

Comment: You can't isolate dependent limits like that.  A good example is $e = \lim_{n\to\infty}(1 + \frac 1n)^{n}\ne (\lim_{n\to\infty} 1+\frac 1n)^{\lim_{n\to\infty}n}=1^{\lim_{n\to\infty}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}1^n=1$.  The error is that the expression $(1+\frac 1n)^{stuff}$ and the $stuff^n$ are not independent what the $stuff$ is will be determined by the value of $n$ so you can't simply isolate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this argument that "proves" that $1=0$. Write
$$1=\frac1n+\frac1n+\cdots+\frac1n\qquad(n\text{ times})$$
Now since $1/n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, it follows that 
$$1=\lim_{n\to\infty}1=0+\cdots+0=0.$$
Your situation is analogous. Notice that the number of terms in the sum (or product in your case) depends on $n$.

Comment: Right that makes sense! Do you know how could I possibly prove it tends to infinity though?

Comment: @JustWandering You can find a proof for example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514388/find-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtnn?rq=1